# Export-csv return 1 instance instead a whole resutls

Tags: powershell, csv

Don't know why Exporting csv return only 1 object instead the whole result. Why is that if function is in the loop ?

```
$names = Import-CSV C:\PowerShell\UpdatePhone\Telefony_1.csv -Header Givenname,Surname -Delimiter ","
ForEach ($Name in $Names)
{
    $FirstFilter = $Name.Givenname
    $SecondFilter = $Name.Surname
    Foreach-object{
    Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter { GivenName -like $FirstFilter -and Surname -like $SecondFilter}|select samaccountname,name,employeeID,mail,ipphone, mobile| Export-Csv C:\PowerShell\UpdatePhone\Telefony.csv
}}
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because each time it is creating/exporting a new file with the last object. You should use `-append`

**Change this**

```
Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter { GivenName -like $FirstFilter -and Surname -like $SecondFilter}|select samaccountname,name,employeeID,mail,ipphone, mobile| Export-Csv C:\PowerShell\UpdatePhone\Telefony.csv
```

**To:**

```
Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter { GivenName -like $FirstFilter -and Surname -like $SecondFilter}|select samaccountname,name,employeeID,mail,ipphone, mobile| Export-Csv C:\PowerShell\UpdatePhone\Telefony.csv -Append
```

PS: I have not gone through the logic that you are persisting for doing so. I just corrected the fundamental problem.

Comment: It should be more efficient to gather the whole foreach output in a variable and do an `Export-Csv` only once.

Comment: @LotPings: I second you. That's why I mentioned that I didn't touch the logic so far.